# Constructor functions in js

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, hasownproperty

Trying to understand the outputs below - why are the checks false when directly used on objects - but true when checked on instances ?? can some one explain - am I missing something here?

```
    function Book2(){
    this.title =  "High Performance JavaScript";
    this.publisher = "Yahoo! Press";
};

Book2.prototype.author = "hgghghg";

var b = new Book2();

alert(Book2.hasOwnProperty("title"));  //false
alert(Book2.hasOwnProperty("toString"));  //false
alert("title" in Book2); //false
alert("toString" in Book2); //true


alert(b.hasOwnProperty("title"));  //true
alert(b.hasOwnProperty("toString"));  //false
alert("title" in b); //true 
alert("toString" in b); //true
```

Comment: *"why are the checks false when directly used on objects - but true when checked on instances"* - Instances *are* objects. Functions are objects. The prototype is an object too. But they aren't the same objects, and they don't all share the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

`Book2` does not have a `title` attribute, it only sets a title attribute on a `new` object. `Book2` does *inherit* the `toString` method from its prototype.

`hasOwnProperty`, as the name suggests, tells you whether this particular object itself has the given property. It does ***not*** look at the prototype.
`in` tells you whether the object has the property *anywhere*, including its prototype chain.

Comment: actually just changed the subject - my question was - when I use these properties on Book2 vs b - why are the results different.

Comment: Err, same answer...!?

Answer (score 0):

`hasOwnProperty` does not look at the prototype chain, the `in` operator does

Also, `Book` is a function, it does not have its own properties, it inherits methods like `apply` and `call`. Creating an instance of `Book` with `new` will create an object whose prototype chain starts with `Book.prototype` so it will see properties like `title`.

Comment: Functions does not have properties? Can you please clarify..I was under the assumption that the Book2  here will have the properties.

Comment: No, what will be inherited is when you call `a=new Book()`, `a` will inherit the properties from `Book.prototype`. `Book` does not inherit from `Book.prototype`

Comment: why does Book2 have to inherit - 'title' for example - it has it already - so when I do 'Book2.hasOwnProperty("title")' why is this false?

Comment: No, the object Book2, which is a function, does *not* have a title property. The line starting `this.title =` creates a title property on the object created when Book2 is called, not on Book2 itself.

Comment: Book2 has a prototype property, it does not have a title property